# separar una lista en 2 listas, una de strings y otra de números

Tags: python

si me pudieran ayudar con esto sería de mucha utilidad para mi.
Tengo separar una lista en 2 listas, una de strings y otra de números. La verdad no estoy muy seguro de como hacerlo, quizá con un ciclo que vaya recorriendo elemento por elemento y los vaya clasificando. Cualquier tipo de orientación es bienvenida, ya que soy nuevo en esto de programar.

Comment: Pues tú mismo lo has dicho. Creas un par de listas vacías, una para números otra para strings. Luego iteras en un bucle for por tu lista a cada elemento le haces `if type(elemento) == int` (o `str`) y lo añades con `.append()` a una de las listas antes mencionadas.

Comment: Dividir para reinar. Divide el problema en subproblemas: 1) como recorrer una lista; 2) como identificar un número; 3) como identificar un string; 4) como agregar un elemento a una lista. Un paso a la vez te llevara a la meta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

La búsqueda forzada funcionaria, sin embargo, aquí te dejo un camino algo diferente:

1. Se convierte la lista a una cadena `cad = " ".join(str(x) for x in lista)`
2. Se extraen los valores enteros en una lista `l_num = [int(num) for num in cad.split() if num.isdigit()]`
3. Se extraen los valores de texto en otra lista `l_str = [str(x) for x in cad.split() if not x.isdigit()]`

**OJO:** Seguramente por debajo se ejecuta la búsqueda forzada, pero supongo que podrías aprender de ambos métodos.

Espero te sirva, Saludos.